# Characters change to Chinese in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online

I am trying to add a shapefile to ArcGIS Online (as zip), but somehow the characters in the attribute table displays as Chinese.

This is what it looks like in ArcMap:
[image]

And this is the result in AGOL:
[image]

I'm sure there's a setting I'm missing, but which one? How do I get correct character encoding?

The CPG file contains this: `ISO 885910`, which, according to Wikipedia, corresponds to

> Western Europe with rationalised character set for Nordic languages,
>   including complete Icelandic set

While I originally had nordic characters in the attribute table, this version of the shapefile does not.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify whether a .CPG file exists, and if so, its contents.

Comment: @Vince, I updated the question

Comment: AGOL is only going to be able to use shapefiles in UTF-8 encoding.  If the data is ASCII-7, you might try removing/renaming the .CPG file.  Writing other-than UTF-8 as UTF-8 in shapefile through ArcGIS is possible, but I'm not sufficiently expert to write an answer on the topic.

Comment: If you want to keep Nordic characters, keep your features in personal or FGDB

Comment: Removing the CPG file helped. Next time I'll keep it in a database instead. I'll write up a short answer for future readers. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Summary of the comments by Vince and FelixIP.*

Removing the CPG file among the shapefile files resolved the character encoding issue in AGOL.

> AGOL is only going to be able to use shapefiles in UTF-8 encoding. If
>   the data is ASCII-7, you might try removing/renaming the .CPG file.

It is possible that by using a database one will avoid this problem, but I have not had the chance to test this yet.